# In Jenkins, what plugins and/or configurations should I use to promote/redeploy Docker images and Git branches

Tags: jenkins

I have set up a Jenkins job using the multibranch plugin. Via my `Jenkinsfile`, Jenkins executes the following steps:

- Build: `docker-compose build`
- Test
- Push Git ref to internal Git repository
- Tag local Docker images with branch and build number
- Push local Docker images and tags to internal Nexus repository
- Calculate the deploy host name

  - This is a Docker host that runs the new, deployed code
  - My deploy code looks up the Git branch, and from that derives the Docker host that it should deploy to
- Start Ansible AWX deployment job

  - AWX deploys the given images/tags/git refs to the requested deploy host
- Monitor AWX for successful job completion

Because of the multibranch plugin, this works to build and deploy from any branch. However now I would like to set up build promotion. By this I mean:

- I build branch `dev`.
- Jenkins starts a job on branch `dev`. From here on, we'll call this "job 100".
- Jenkins generates Docker tag `dev-100`, based on the Jenkins "job 100"
- Jenkins deploys to Docker host "myapp.dev.mydomain".

  - Up to here is described above
- I do more tests, for instance QA.
- I take some kind of action to "promote" Jenkins "job 100".

  - "promote" means I want to reuse and re-tag the artifacts from "job 100". From here on, we'll say I'm promoting to `prod`.
  - **THIS** is the part I am asking how to do
- Jenkins starts job 5 on branch `prod`
- Jenkins re-tags `dev-100` Docker images as `prod-5`

  - The current multibranch approach builds a **new** `prod-5` Docker image instead of **re-tagging** the existing `dev-100` Docker image
- Jenkins pushes `prod-build-5` to "myapp.prod.mydomain".

How can I promote and re-tag, either with the multibranch plugin, or via some other approach?

Comment: I don't know what "I promote Jenkins job 100. " means. The answer to your question depends alot on other information like how do you do releases, what is your branch strategy etc. 

You could probably run a all the tests and if they all pass just retag your `dev-100` image as `prod-build-5`. 

You could also have only dev tests run on PR's, qa tests run on `develop` branch and prod tagging on master/main branch.